# Will we gain some extra hours if we travel in the direction of the rotation of the earth?

Tags: time, earth, rotation, conventions

I heard that If we travel for long distances in the direction of the rotation of the earth, we can gain some extra hours in the journey.
Is it true? What if we travel in the opposite direction?

Comment: The surface of the Earth at the equator is going roughly 1000 Mph so you'd need to travel at least that (at the equator) to go "backwards in time".  This isn't a physics question though since how we define time based on the rotation of the Earth is completely arbitrary.

Comment: This question is about an arbitrary convention of time and not any physical process or principle.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you'll gain extra hours, but you'll lose them on the way back, unless you keep going round.

Let's assume you're in a plane flying along the equator, moving at 800 km/h (in the direction of the earth's travel) - a normal jetplane speed. The earth is rotating so that a point stationary on the equator moves at 1600 km/h. That means that, for every km you move, the earth has moved 2 km. Hence you will see the sun moving in its arc to the west at half its normal speed.

Since the local time is set (approximately!) by the position of the sun in the sky, that means that your **local** time is indeed slowed down to half speed. If, after 1 hr travel you land, you'll find that the time on the ground has advanced only 30 min.

If you could keep travelling at 1600 km/h you would find that the sun seems to stay in the same position in the sky, and your local time stays the same.

When you travel in the other direction, the same happens in reverse and, when you get back to your departure, you've lost all the time you've gained. If you keep going in the same direction you'll eventually cross the International Date Line, and suddenly the date will roll back 1 day. When you get back to your departure this way, you will have gained a day. Magellan's sailors were very worried when, on their return from the first round-the-world trip, they discovered they had gained a day. If the missing day was a Sunday they would have missed going to church that day, which meant damnation in hell!

Note that we're only talking about apparent time, the time as measured by the position of the sun. You will still keep ageing while you're flying. Of course, because of General Relativity, your speed and height also affect your real ageing so that, when you land, you may be some microseconds younger than someone who stayed on the ground.